# Database always adding 9 empty rows

Tags: php, mysql

So I am importing data from an .asc file and I am putting it into a database. Everything gets inserted but in the beginning it has a little problem.
This is the code:

```
<?php
function importdb()
{
    include('db_config.php');
    $File       = 'lijst.csv';
    $File2      = 'preise.asc';
    $handle     = fopen($File, "r");
    $handle2    = fopen($File2, "r");
    $arrResult  = array();
    $arrResult2 = array();
    fgetcsv($handle);
    fgetcsv($handle);
    fgetcsv($handle);
    fgetcsv($handle);
    fgetcsv($handle);
    fgetcsv($handle);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE && ($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        //---------------------
        $artikelnmr       = $data[0];
        $barcode          = $data[1];
        $omschrijving_nl  = $data[2];
        $omschrijving_exp = $data[3];
        $bruto_prs        = $data[4];
        $staffel_prs      = $data[5];
        $aktie_prs        = $data[6];
        $bruto_antl       = $data[8];
        $staffel_antl     = $data[9];
        $aktie_aantal     = $data[10];
        $voorraad         = $data[15];
        $leverdatum       = $data[16];
        $besteld          = $data[17];
        $pallet_antl      = $data[19];
        $artikel_groep    = $data[22];
        $extra_info       = $data[27];
        //------------------------
        $type             = $data2[0];
        $artikel          = $data2[1];
        $prijs1           = $data2[6];
        $prijs2           = $data2[7];
        $prijs3           = $data2[8];
        $prijs4           = $data2[9];
        $prijs5           = $data2[10];
        //----------------------
        $stmt             = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `producten`(`id`, `artikelnr`, `barcode`, `omschrijving_nl`, `omschrijving_exp`, `bruto_prijs`, `bruto_aant`, `staffel_prijs`, `staffel_aantal`, `aktie_prijs`, `aktie_aantal`, `voorraad`, `leverdatum`, `besteld`, `pallet_aantal`, `artikel_groep`, `extra`)
                VALUES ('', :artikelnmr,:barcode,:omschrijving_nl,:omschrijving_exp,:bruto_prijs,:bruto_aantal,:staffel_prijs,:staffel_aantal,:aktie_prijs,:aktie_aantal,:voorraad,:leverdatum,:besteld,:pallet_aantal,:artikel_groep,:extra)");
        $stmt2            = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `prijzen`(`artikelnr`, `prijs_soort`, `prijs1`, `prijs2`, `prijs3`, `prijs4`, `prijs5`) VALUES (:nmr, :soort, :prijs1, :prijs2, :prijs3, :prijs4, :prijs5)");
        //----------------------
        $stmt->bindParam(":artikelnmr", $artikelnmr);
        $stmt->bindParam(":barcode", $barcode);
        $stmt->bindParam(":omschrijving_nl", $omschrijving_nl);
        $stmt->bindParam(":omschrijving_exp", $omschrijving_exp);
        $stmt->bindParam(":bruto_prijs", $bruto_prs);
        $stmt->bindParam(":bruto_aantal", $bruto_antl);
        $stmt->bindParam(":staffel_aantal", $staffel_antl);
        $stmt->bindParam(":staffel_prijs", $staffel_prs);
        $stmt->bindParam(":aktie_aantal", $aktie_aantal);
        $stmt->bindParam(":aktie_prijs", $aktie_prs);
        $stmt->bindParam(":voorraad", $voorraad);
        $stmt->bindParam(":leverdatum", $leverdatum);
        $stmt->bindParam(":besteld", $besteld);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pallet_aantal", $pallet_antl);
        $stmt->bindParam(":artikel_groep", $artikel_groep);
        $stmt->bindParam(":extra", $extra_info);
        //----------------------
        $stmt2->bindParam("nmr", $artikel);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":soort", $type);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs1", $prijs1);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs2", $prijs2);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs3", $prijs3);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs4", $prijs4);
        $stmt2->bindParam(":prijs5", $prijs5);
        //----------------------
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $artikel . ': ' . $type . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($handle2);

}
importdb();
?>
```

This only happens in the second statement (stmt2). Everything is okay in the first statement (stmt)
This is what happens in the database and what should be put in the first few lines:

[Database Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hEGy.png)
[What should be inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgaM.png)

Do I need to skip a few lines just like I did in the first file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you double-checked the file? Maybe there are lines that are blank.

Comment: Already found it out. artikelnr had to be a varchar not an int